# AngularJS Noob: How would I test a factory that uses $resource?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple factory:

```
app.factory('WomensSunglass', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource("/api/products/womens_sunglasses", {}, {
    query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
  });
}]);
```

How exactly would I test this? Factories are considered the "M" in "MVC" in Angular right? I'm used to testing models with database tables, not so much as API response getters so I don't know how to test it. Would I just stub the request with a preset response? What would that even accomplish?

Answer (score -1):

There are more examples of testing factories/services out there than I care to count. Rather than downvote your question because you didn't bother to Google things, I'll give you a couple of links:

http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-karma.html

https://github.com/daniellmb/angular-test-patterns

You might also look at the Angular source code to see how they test things, as well as the Angular-UI project to see how they test things.

Comment: Thanks for the resources, but they cover everything. Could you point me to the place where I can read on how to test what I'm looking for specifically?